# argparse mutual exclusive group issue

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to achieve the following functionality using argparse. The example usage is given below:

```
$ test.py -ip 17.208.127.143 --current
>>> OUTPUT1

$ test.py -ip 17.208.127.143 --set 25 
>>> OUTPUT2
```

OR

```
$ test.py -ip 17.208.127.143 --set 25 --time 30
>>> OUTPUT3
```

"current" argument requires no parameter. "set" argument requires a number to be passed to it. "current" and "set" arguments can't be used together. "time" argument can be used only if "set" argument is present. What's the best way to achieve this? I'm using the following currently:

```
parser.add_argument("--ip", help="IP Address", required=True)
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("--current", help="Current setting", required=False, action="store_true")
group.add_argument("--set", help="Set the value", required=False)
parser.add_argument("--time", help="Time duration", required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Can this be further optimized?

Comment: Optimization doesn't make much sense when using `argparse`.  It is run once, so speed doesn't matter.  Readability/maintainability does matter.  Anyways, there isn't a neat way of testing for 'inclusivity'.  You have to do that yourself.  But with the right `default` you might not even need to test that.

Comment: Try subparsers, with default `argparse` you can't achieve it.

Comment: Is it a problem if the user gives `--current` and `--time` and then `--time` is simply ignored?